# Is GDataXMLNode fast?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

Just curious, I've always been using `TBXML` & `NSXMLParser` to do my parsing, but I just found out about `GDataXMLNode`, and what intrigues me is that it has the capability to use `XPath`.   That's a huge bonus in my opinion.  However, I don't want to make my app unnecessarily slow just to make it easier for myself.   Any opinions?

**Edit:**
Oops, I just found this:
[image]

But please, I would still like to hear any opinions about using this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an open source test application that uses all the XML parsers I could find, including the ones you mention, and TBXML is clearly the fastest you can find so far.

It's here:
https://github.com/akosma/iPhoneWebServicesClient

Comment: Yeah TBXML is really fast, but I grew tired of having no XPath support. By the time I started doing loops just to find the element I wanted, it got kinda slow. I just wanted to know if GData is good. Thanks for putting that project together! I don't have a server I can use to test it, though. :(

Comment: You can run the server on your local machine using MAMP, for example, it's only PHP.

Comment: I'm not adept enough in other languages to set up something like that.  I'm happy with the sample data you provided. :)